# Errorlogs with timestamp

Tags: powershell

I'm having difficulty adding timestamp into this simple command. Anyway I can add timestamp either before or after the error? There are other scripts that I want to include timestamp and if this can be done it would help out a lot.

```
Rename-Item C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download Download.old -Confirm:$false -Verbose -ErrorAction Continue *>> c:\temp\verbose.txt
```

The result when item does not exist is this:

```
    Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download Destination: C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download.old".
    Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download' does not exist.
    At line:1 char:1

+ Rename-Item C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download Download.old -Co ...
```

Comment: Timestamp of _what_? The directory you're moving? The current time?

Comment: Are you seeking to capture the error messages?

Comment: adding this `2>&1` to the end of a line of code will redirect the error stream to the output stream. that can be assigned to a $Var ... and that can be sent to your logging file. you can also use the `$Error[0]` automatic var to get the last error.

Comment: I'm looking for timestamp for the execution of the command or rather the timestamp of when this error is captured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a log function:

```
function Write-Log
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [String] $Message 
    )

    process
    {
        $logMessage = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF}: {1}" -f (Get-Date), $Message

        Write-Information $logMessage
        Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\verbose.txt" -Append -InputObject $logMessage
    }
}

$InformationPreference = "Continue"

Write-Log "Renaming 'Download' to 'Download.old'"
Rename-Item "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download" "Download.old" -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction Continue *>> "c:\temp\verbose.txt"
Write-Log "Finished renaming 'Download' to 'Download.old'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much